# Почему слово "турок" склоняется по второму склонению в единственном числе и по первому во множественном?

Tags: склонение

Источник: [Турок на wikitionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA).

По логике форма винительного падежа множественного числа слова "турок" в значении "лицо турецкой национальности" должна быть "турков", но в словарях зафиксировано написание "турок" (кого? Мн. ч, В. п.).

Есть ли другие слова, которые в разных формах склоняются по-разному? Есть ли у этого явления название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, **о видах склонения** существительных **в форме мн.числа** **говорить не совсем корректно**, так как в этом случае мы имеем **обобщенный набор окончаний**: одинаковые окончания АМ/ЯМ, АМИ/ЯМИ, АХ/ЯХ для трех падежей и вариации окончаний в И.п.и Р. п.

В форме мн. числа Р.р. используются **три вида окончаний**: ОВ/ЕВ, нулевое и ЕЙ, причем после твердых основ часто конкурируют **две формы: ОВ и нулевое**.

Три вида окончаний Р.п. определяются **как основные и вариантные для сущ. РАЗНЫХ СКЛОНЕНИЙ.** Для сущ. 1-го скл. основным является нулевое окончание (стена - стен), а для сущ. 2-го скл. м.рода - окончание ОВ (стол - столов). В то же время существительные м.рода могут иметь **вариантное нулевое окончание**, при этом их   можно разделить НА 5 ГРУПП:

Группа 1. **Названия лиц по социальной, национальной, территориальной принадлежности** 
Вариантное нулевое окончание в Р. п. мн. числа имеют следующие существительные: **турок, грузин, цыган**, но: арабов, киргизов – основное окончание ОВ.

Группа 2. **Парные предметы**
 Вариантное нулевое окончание в Р. п. мн. числа имеют существительные, обозначающие парные предметы: пара ботинок, чулок, погон, но: пара носков – основное окончание ОВ:

Группа 3.  **Воинские подразделения**
 Вариантное нулевое окончание используется в существительных, обозначающих старые воинские части при СОБИРАТЕЛЬНОМ значении существительного (отряд гусар).

Основное окончание ОВ пишется при обозначении ОТДЕЛЬНЫХ ЛИЦ, в том числе в сочетаниях с ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ (пять гусаров),  а также в существительных, обозначающих современные  воинские части (группа саперов).

Группа 4. **Название единиц измерения**
Вариантное нулевое окончание употребляется в сочетании слов ампер, ватт, вольт, герц, рентген с числительными.

Слова гектар, грамм, килограмм, Ом  имеют книжную форму с окончанием ОВ и разговорную форму с нулевым окончанием.

Группа 5. **Название овощей и плодов**

В этом случае нет вариантных окончаний, но используются РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ ОСНОВНЫЕ окончания для существительных разных склонений и родов: 
килограмм яблок, груш, слив – основное нулевое окончание в сущ. ж.р. и ср.р., но: килограмм апельсинов, помидоров, баклажанов – основное окончание ОВ  существительных м.р.

Встречающиеся  в разговорной речи варианты с нулевым окончанием существительных м.р. не являются нормативными, то есть не допускаются выражения: килограмм абрикос, мандарин, помидор.

**Вывод:** сущ. "турок" (м.р.) имеет вариантное нулевое окончание, но это не единственное вариантное окончание в этой тематической группе. Фонетика у слова особая (с беглой гласной), форма устоявшаяся, поэтому **вряд ли можно ждать каких-либо изменений.**

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке есть целый ряд существительных с основой на твёрдую согласную, имеющие нулевое окончание в родительном падеже:

Ср.: один солдат – несколько солдат; один грузин – несколько грузин, один цыган – несколько цыган,один осетин — пятеро осетин,один чулок — нет чулок.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, что по этому поводу писал А. С. Пушкин

> Как надобно писать: турков или турок? то и другое правильно. Турок и турка равно употребительны.

Потом, слово "турка" даже стало превалировать, и литературное множественное число закрепилось от первого склонения. Однако, когда в XX в. отношения с Турцией наладились, "турка" стало звучать несколько пренебрижительно и было поностью вытеснено "турком", множественное же число пока не изменилось, но думаю в недалёком будущем и оно подтянется.